# Summing RMS Values

Tags: signal-analysis, real-time

I'm trying to calculate the RMS of a signal whilst only having access to the current RMS values of the waveforms making it up.  This is because I need to calculate the total RMS so I can use it to drive a sidechain.

I have no access to the actual audio data (it's in a hardware-decoded format) nor the final mix (that happens on the hardware).  Just the RMS curves over time of the individual samples which I precalculated before encoding them.

Mathematically, summing the RMSes doesn't work, but is there a technique that would give me a near-enough value if only considering recorded audio?

The equation for orthagonal waveforms actually gives reasonable results:

```
rms = sqrt( rms_a^2 + rms_b^2 + ... + rms_z^2 )
```

...but there's enough occasional big differences to concern me.

Comment: You need to divide by N inside the sqrt.

Comment: The equation you show works only if the signals are independent / uncorrelated. A test of independence would be if the equation works.

Comment: @jaket That's from the Wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) - "Waveforms made by summing known simple waveforms have an RMS value that is the root of the sum of squares of the component RMS values."  These _aren't_ simple waveforms, but it's the closest I got to the actual RMS of the combined waveforms.

Comment: @DanBoschen They're certainly different waveforms, but it depends what you mean by "independent."  The chances of them being similar sounding is high, but they'd be triggered at different times.

Comment: @subi211 Assuming that the individual RMS calculations are from consecutive, non-overlapping but equal sized time intervals then it is a different problem from summing of simple waveforms.

Comment: @jaket The continuous signal would be made up of several recorded waveforms being triggered at arbitrary times, sometimes overlapping other times not.  I know there's no way of computing the exact RMS with the infomation I have available, but is there a good approximation?